# How are Zend Framework JSON Endpoint Created?

Tags: php, json, zend-framework

Where in the code below is the /home/dashboardfilegrid JSON endpoint URL created? 
Does a new model automatically result in a new JSON Endpoint URL?

### Environment

Zend Server - Version 5.1.0
PHP - Version 5.3.6
Zend Framework - Version 1.11.3
MySQL - Version 5.1.52

## View

```
var gridDOC = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                         store     : new dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore({ url : "/home/dashboardfilegrid" }),
                         structure : [
                                      {name: "Rowid", field: "ID", hidden: true},
                                      {name: "Service Provider #", field: "SPNCD", width : "6"},
                                      {name: "File Name", field : "NAME", width : "11"},
                                      {name: "Posted Date", field : "CREATED", width : "11"},
                                      {name: "Download",field: "cover", width: "auto", formatter:showDownload}
                                    ]
                 }, "gridNodeDOC");

gridDOC.startup();
```

## Model

```
public function fileDownload($uid) {
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter ();
    $sql = $db->query ( 'SELECT B.ID, C.SPNCD, B.NAME, B.CREATED, B.CONTENT
    FROM USER_SPN A, DOCUMENT B, SPN C
    WHERE B.SRCTYP = "SPN"
    AND B.SOURCEID = A.SPNID
    AND A.SPNID = C.ID
    AND A.UID =' . $db->quote($uid) );
    $dbvalue = $sql->fetchAll ();
    return $dbvalue;
}
```

## Controller

```
public function dashboardfilegridAction() {
    $data       = new Default_Model_Dashboard();
    $fileData   = $data->fileDownload( $this->userauth->uid );
    $dojoData   = new Zend_Dojo_Data( 'ID', $fileData );

    echo $dojoData;
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a function with function name that ends with "Action" in the controller, it will become an "endpoint". e.g. **dashboardfilegridAction** for **/dashboardfilegrid/**.

If you camelcase the function name, it will be accessible with the words separated by '-'. e.g. **dashboardFilegridAction** will be **/dashboard-filegrid/**.

Comment: Is there a limit on the amount of data the endpoint will hold before resulting in 500 Internal Server Error?

Comment: There are limits in php: post_max_size, memory_limit and upload_max_filesize. Usually I only need to increase upload_max_filesize for receiving large file. Other defaults should be enough for most purposes. Btw, you should update your environment :)